# Set path to composer.json when run composer.phar command

Tags: shell, composer-php, sh

I have composer.phar file in my project placed in a folder `project/web/install` and a `composer.json` file placed in `project/composer.json`. How can I specify path to composer.json file in my shell script file which is also placed in `project/web/install`

Answer (score 7):

When you are in the directory of the `deployer.phar` file you can do `php composer.phar --working-dir=../../` to specify the location of the `composer.json` file.

Comment: I have two folders in my project root: api and frontend. the api contains Symfony and the frontend contains Vue. _--working-dir_ solved my composer as command line tool problem in PhpStorm. I've added the parameter to Tool Path and it worked. Thank you.